# First language for iOS? Rubymotion vs C, Objective C vs others

Tags: objective-c, c, rubymotion

I have no coding experience except for some basic VBA programming to help out my financial models (read: I have 0 coding experience or background). However, I would love to start developing for the iOS or OSX as a hobby and maybe take it further later on.

For the past day or two, I've been researching the best first lanaguge to learn. Should I go directly to C and then Objective C or should I learn something more high level like Ruby and Rubymotion? I'm open to all sorts of suggestions.

Thanks!

Comment: This question might fit better on http://programmers.stackexchange.com instead.

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking to go straight into iOS, you might as well go directly into Objective C.  Objective C is different enough from pretty much any other "common" language (Java, C#, VB, etc) that knowing another language won't really help you.  You should, however, know the basic concepts that encapsulate all programming.

If you're looking at learning to code for iOS to do mobile apps, the following courses through iTunes could be of considerable help to you.  They're from Stanford University, and are free.

https://itunes.apple.com/us/course/coding-together-developing/id593208016?l=en
https://itunes.apple.com/us/course/developing-ios-7-apps-for/id733644550

Comment: As well, no matter what language you choose, you're still going to have to be able to read the documentation and system APIs, all of which are written in terms of Objective-C.

Answer (score 2):

There are two things you will need to learn in order to develop iOS apps: how to program, in general, and how the iOS SDK (software development kit) works in particular.

Learning the iOS SDK is a “fixed cost” that doesn’t have anything to do with which programming language you choose. You’re going to have to know that (for example) if you want to display an alert to the user you’ll have to instantiate a UIAlertView object and set some properties on it. That is the case regardless of the programming language.

Since almost all of the existent example code for iOS is written in Objective-C, however, you’ll be best served learning that language to begin with. Objective-C is a fine candidate for your first language, so taken together the “learn to program” and “learn the SDK” tasks will be easiest if you start by learning Objective-C.

(For what it’s worth I’d recommend Aaron Hillegass’s *[iOS Programming: The Big Nerd Ranch Guide](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321821521)*, but of course there are tons of free and paid ways to learn Objective-C and Cocoa.)

Comment: I'd also recommend The Big Nerd Ranch Guide.  It's a very good resource.